# Datatable only has one row when it should have many c# (using MySQLDataAdapter) for datagrid view

Tags: c#, mysql

I`m having a problem displaying some data on a datagrid view. I send data to MySQL on form2 and then its supposed to be displayed in a datagrid view in form1. The datagrid view is updating perfectly but it seems that the datatable is not getting populated with the full information. There are 2 rows of data that should be displayed. I get 2 empty rows in datagrid view.I checked the database and the information is there. Is it my query that isnt right?

What I need are all the rows that have temp_quote.quote_id in the quotes_idquotes column. Can you help me out? Here is the code:

```
public void RefreshGrid_parts()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from shopmanager.parts where quotes_idquotes = '" + temp_quote.quote_id + "';",con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "# Assembly";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "assemblies_assembly_id";

        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "# Part";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "part_number";

        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "# Item";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "items_items_id";

        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "# Description";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "part_description";

        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Drawing Revision";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "drawing_rev";

        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Quantity";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "quantity";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: first of all you should try using parameters and not string string in strings just for security reasons and it also takes care of parsing your input.

Comment: Also could you show whats inside the temp_quote.quote_id variable. and what the table content looks like

Comment: This is an internal query. No input from the user is required so there is no problem with security but could you share an example code? Thanks a million.

Comment: temp_quote.quote_id contains the number 20 which is the right info.

Comment: the table contains the following: Part_id, quotes_idquotes, assemblies_assembly_id, items_items_id, client_info_client_number, part_number, part_description, drawing_rev, quantity, date_oredicted, date_required, part_selling_price, part_buying_price, plan_location.

Comment: could you show us what data types the columns have?

Comment: also if the code is only an example and the table is filled else were you maybe have a bug while filling the table and not while displaying it.

Comment: "This is an internal query." Variables can be changed in memory. it's still insecure ;)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I didnt know that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your property example:
(yes its mssql but the logic is the same just change the types, I don't have the mysql lib at hand right know. i guess you'll figure it out.)

```
SqlClient.SqlCommand comand = new SqlClient.SqlCommand("Select * From ExampleTable Where Colum1 = $1");
comand.Parameters.Add(new SqlClient.SqlParameter("$1", "1234") { DbType = DbType.Int32 });
```

this will also parse the decimal string into the correct data type (int32)

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the lines that create the headers to test if your data will appear in the DataGrid. Also put the AutoGenerateColumns to true. If it does, check the DataPropertyName if it's exactly the names of the columns on your query.

```
public void RefreshGrid_parts()
{
    ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from shopmanager.parts where quotes_idquotes = '" + temp_quote.quote_id + "';",con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);

    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    //dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;

    //dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "# Assembly";
    //dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "assemblies_assembly_id";

    //dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "# Part";
    //dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "part_number";

    //dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "# Item";
    //dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "items_items_id";

    //dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "# Description";
    //dataGridView1.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "part_description";

    //dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Drawing Revision";
    //dataGridView1.Columns[4].DataPropertyName = "drawing_rev";

    //dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Quantity";
    //dataGridView1.Columns[5].DataPropertyName = "quantity";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried and all the columns from the database show up but only Part_id is filled in. All other fields are empty.

Comment: this would show more columns than he wants to see also using the DataPropertyName should work fine.

Comment: @ChristianVerner could you show us what data types the columns have?

Comment: Post to us the result of the query, please.

Comment: Part_id is INT(11), quotes_idquotes is INT(11), assemblies_assembly_id is INT(11), items_items_id is INT(11), client_info_client_number is INT(11), part_number is VARCHAR(45), part_description is VARCHAR(45), drawing_rev is VARCHAR(45), quantity is INT, date_predicted is DATE, date_required is DATE, part_selling_price is FLOAT, part_buying_price is FLOAT, plan_location is VARCHAR(45). Thanks guys, i'm new at this so I realy appreciate your help.

Comment: I just tried the query in MySQL workbench and it's returning all the values. I simply replaced the variable with the actual variable value and it works perfectly. I don't get why the info is not in dt.

Answer (score 0):

maybe take Rodrigos suggestion and just let the control generate the columns.
if you want to only this six columns just change the query.

```
public void RefreshGrid_parts()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select assemblies_assembly_id as '# Assembly', part_number as '# Part', items_items_id as '# Item', part_description as '# Description', drawing_rev as 'Drawing Revision', quantity as 'Quantity'  from shopmanager.parts where quotes_idquotes = $1;",con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("$1", temp_quote.quote_id) { DbType = DbType.Int32 });
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I got this error with the provided code. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'Unknown column '$1' in 'where clause''. I'll try to fix that but I think you are on to something with changing the query. I had not thought of that.

Comment: ok, I fixed the error and the datagrid view is showing the right columns but they are still empty. I checked the database and all the info is there. I don't get it. This is the weirdest thing.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like an idiot. The code is good. The problem was that the text color in the datagrid view was white in a white box so I could not see it. Sorry to have bothered you guys with this. 24 hours spent on a non-existing problem! Wow!